# How to run script after input device is added?

Tags: udev, xmodmap, xinput

I want to run a script, when I add an input device. On the one hand I need to run xmodmap, when an external keyboard is added to get there my key bindings. I achieved that already partial with a udev rule. Everything worked except the xmodmap command.
On the other hand I want to run some command when a stylus pen is registered and is added to output of xinput.
As it is no device in /dev I can't see how to achieve that with udev.

Can someone give me some ideas how to get those two things done?

Thank you for help in advance!